# Java - using an array as a parameter in a method giving .class expected error

Tags: java, arrays, parameters

I wrote this code to assign grades to the amount of students and display them in a certain way. I got ".class" and ";" expected errors for line 22 which is `int maxGrade = maxGrade(int[] Grades);` where I tried to declare the variable `maxGrade` by calling the method `maxGrade()` on `int[]Grades`. I thought this would compile since `maxGrade()` is a non-void method and returns the maximum value of the Grades. Does it give compiling errors because I basically said that `int maxGrade = maxGrade` (as the `maxGrade()` method will return `maxGrade`) or is there a problem with my syntax?

```
 import java.util.*;
public class AssignGrades{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numStudents = scn.nextInt();
    int[] Grades = new int[numStudents]; //each student has one grade
    System.out.println("Enter the grades of " +numStudents + " students");
    for(int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++){
     Grades[i] = scn.nextInt();
    }                         
  }
    public static int convertGrades(int[] Grades){
    int maxGrade = maxGrade(int[] Grades);
    for(int i = 0; i<Grades.length; i++)
      if(Grades[i] >= maxGrade -5){
      return 'A';
    } else if(Grades[i] >= maxGrade -10){
      return 'B';
    } else if(Grades[i] >= maxGrade -15){
      return 'C';
    } else if(Grades[i] >= maxGrade -20){
      return 'D';
    } else {
      return 'F';
    }
  }
  public static int maxGrade(int[] Grades){
    int maxGrade = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < Grades.length; i++){
      if(Grades[i+1] > Grades[i]){
        maxGrade = Grades[i+1];
      } else if(Grades[i] > Grades[i+1]){
        maxGrade = Grades[i];
      } else {
        maxGrade = Grades[i];
      }

    }
    return maxGrade;
  }

}
```

Comment: Just change `int maxGrade = maxGrade(int[] Grades);` to `int maxGrade = maxGrade(Grades);`. The first syntax is only for argument declaration.

Comment: Please, format/indent your code correctly, using the IDE action that doe that for you. And respect the Java naming conventions. You should also always use curly braces around the body of yourcontrol flow statements.

Comment: Hi @yy123q, and welcome to Stack Overflow. You have some answers to your question, but I want to point out one more thing: you asked "Does it give compiling errors because I basically said that int maxGrade = maxGrade (as the maxGrade() method will return maxGrade) ..." - the answer is **no**. Java knows that only variables can be assigned to, and only functions can be invoked, so it knows which `maxGrade` you want based on whether you write `maxGrade` the variable or `maxGrade(...)` the function

Comment: @MyStackRunnethOver I asked this because in the maxGrade() method, I returned the variable maxGrade. But, I do not fully understand what this does to my code.

Comment: Your function is called `maxGrade`. Within it, you declare a variable, `maxGrade`. The function does some things, assigning to the *variable* `maxGrade`. When you write `maxGrade = ...` Java knows you're dealing with the variable. If, inside the method `maxGrade` you wrote `maxGrade(...)` Java would know you meant the method, not the variable, because variables can't be invoked using `<variable>(...)` like methods can. Similarly, `return maxGrade` returns the value of the variable, because you cannot *return* a method, only a variable or a value

Comment: Basically, the same name can be used for both a method and a variable because there is no use case in which it is ambiguous whether you want the method or the variable. The *context* (whether you use `return`, `=`, or `()`, for example) will clearly define which thing of that name goes there. This is why a method and a variable can share the exact same name, but two variables cannot - there are cases in which it would be ambiguous which of the two you meant. In fact, two **methods** can also share the exact same name, if they have different arguments. This is called method overloading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few errors in the code:

1. When you call a method you don't need to put in the type. So you can do just this: `int maxGrade = maxGrade(Grades);`
2. In the for loop you are returning from `if-else`. So it will return when `i=0` and will not cover the rest of the values of `i`.
3. You will have to use a default return in the method `convertGrades()`.

Even after that the logic is not correct. You will have to fix that.

The updated code to make it work(look at the comments for the changes) :

```
import java.util.*;

public class AssignGrades {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Prompt the user for the number of students
        System.out.println("Enter the number of students: ");
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numStudents = scn.nextInt();

        // Variable names start with lower case letter
        int[] grades = new int[numStudents]; // each student has one grade
        System.out.println("Enter the grades of " + numStudents + " students");
        for (int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++) {
            grades[i] = scn.nextInt();
        }

        // Call the method here
        convertGrades(grades);
        scn.close();
    }

    public static void convertGrades(int[] grades) {
        int maxGrade = maxGrade(grades);

        // Use System.out.println to print the values
        for (int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
            if (grades[i] >= maxGrade - 5) {
                System.out.println("A");
            } else if (grades[i] >= maxGrade - 10) {
                System.out.println("B");
            } else if (grades[i] >= maxGrade - 15) {
                System.out.println("C");
            } else if (grades[i] >= maxGrade - 20) {
                System.out.println("D");
            } else {
                System.out.println("F");
            }
        }
    }

    public static int maxGrade(int[] grades) {
        int maxGrade = 0;

        // Shorten this
        for (int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
           if(maxGrade < grades[i]) {
               maxGrade = grades[i];
           }
        }
        return maxGrade;
    }
}
```

Comment: For the second one, is it better to just go with the first if statement? Also, what part of my logic is wrong and how can I change it?

Comment: @yy123q Do you want to store the grades in an array or just print it?

Comment: I want to print them.

Comment: Thanks a lot, one more question: why do I need to use scn.close(); ?

Comment: @yy123q That's a good practice. Also if the answer helped you can you please mark the answer as accepted?